# Simple SQL query with Autonumbers

Tags: sql, ms-access, primary-key, autonumber

I don't understand whats wrong.

I have a primary key in my Microsoft Access database known as SessionID. It is an autonumber has the format "3"00000.

So say I have a SessionID such as 300001.

If I have a query such as;

```
SELECT Booking.SessionID FROM Booking WHERE Booking.SessionID = 300001
```

Nothing comes up! Its got me dumbfounded and I have nearly redone half of my database trying to solve this problem.

If you guys could point out the obvious flaw, it would be great. If not, then that means its a problem somewhere in my program which would still be of great help!

Comment: Can you give us a couple of rows of sample data? :)

Answer (score 2):

Formats are just pictures and a format on a primary key like this will only ever lead to confusion. The value of the key is 1, not 300001.